# Is it possible to render just math equations in real time?

Tags: filetype-tex, previewing

I have been using neovim to write LaTeX/Markdown for a while and it brings really great experience. Since I usually write equations, I'm wondering is there any plugin to render and just render math in real time?

For Markdown, a solution could be the [markdown-preview.nvim](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim) plugin, which performs real-time rendering for the whole document, including equations. For LaTeX, I tried running `latexmk -pvc` in back end, but it compiles all the source files and so takes a relatively long time.

Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: Maybe what you're asking is simply not feasible. How does it look in your estimation a program that only renders math? Do you want it to drop the surrounding text or what is your idea? If the issue is performance (e.g. "markdown to latex conversion takes too long"), then that should be a better question to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old, but as currently there is no answers, but i am answering this for the people coming here in the future looking for an answer

You can take a look at [tectonic](https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/) which is a modern TeX/LaTeX engine which is relatively fast...

this is used in texlab lsp server (on [github](https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab))

also take a look at[bytesnake/vim-graphical-preview](https://github.com/bytesnake/vim-graphical-preview) which really cool.

There is also effort for same is going into [neorg](https://github.com/nvim-neorg/neorg/commits/latex-rendering) plugin

*shameless plug*
Tectonic is what i am using to currently for trying to build a live previewer plugin based on hologram plugin called [hologram-math-preview.nvim](https://github.com/Vaisakhkm2625/hologram-math-preview.nvim)